# Debugging ajax calls on CakePHP 2 with DebugKit, Firebug et al

Tags: cakephp, firebug, firephp

I have a CakePHP 2 app with DebugKit installed. It is working fine and I get the memory usage and processing time in the "Timing" toolbar for each page I load.

What I also want to be able to do is get memory usage and processing times for ajax requests after the page has loaded. I am aware that I can access previous ajax requests using the "History" button in the DebugKit Toolbar, but this is doesn't really help when I want to click around the page, firing ajax requests and get instant debugging information for them.

So, I did some searching and I found that I could use Firebug + FirePHP in Firefox along with the FirePHP and FireCake libraries in my app and get all of DebugKit's stats on a per-ajax-request basis. This sounds perfect and exactly what I want to do.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to work. I could only find one tutorial on the matter at http://someguyjeremy.com/blog/using-firephp-to-debug-your-cakephp-app

I have done everything that tutorial mentions and Cake gives me no errors at all. However, unless I am missing something, I don't see where in Firebug the debug info is being displayed, if indeed it is even being fed to Firebug in the first place.

My config:

**Cake Version:** 2.2.4

**Firefox Version:** 17.0.1

**Firebug Version:** tried with 1.11.1 and 1.9.0

**FirePHP Version:** 0.7.1

**DebugKit Version:** 2.2.0 (latest master branch)

**UPDATE**

It appears to work perfectly for Ajax requests that do not end in .json and, therefore, are not being picked up by the `Router::parseExtensions('json');` I have in routes.php.

I took out `Router::parseExtensions('json');` and changed my Ajax request to go for my `filter` action directly instead of calling it `filter.json` and Cake serves all of the FireBug headers. Unfortunately, I can't use it like this because JQuery needs the content type to be application.json.

Comment: My site's still available: http://someguyjeremy.com/blog/using-firephp-to-debug-your-cakephp-app

Comment: Do you see Firephp headers in the firebug responses? At the very least with Firebug you can inspect the headers. Look for lots of `X-Wf-X-X-X-XX` headers.

Comment: Also make sure the `Net` tab is enabled.

Comment: @jeremyharris I don't know what the problem was yesterday. When I clicked on your site it was redirecting to a strange url (with the numbers 404 in the actual domain name if I remember correctly) which was subsequently timing out. Anyway, it's working ok now so I have updated the post with the correct URL.

Comment: @jeremyharris I have updated the post with new details. I discovered that this problem is only happening when I am requesting an ajax action that is being routed through `outer::parseExtensions('json');` -- I think that this is the same bug as reported at http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42880/tickets/107-firephp-messages-are-not-sent-in-response-if-using-jsonxmlview-with-serialization but I'm not exactly sure. What do you think?

Comment: the old domain was 42pixels.com, but all links 301 to the new domain. Oh well. That ticket only applies if you're using the automatic serialization, which if you have a view you're not. Are any of the `X-Wf` headers being sent (or better yet post/bin the request/response that you get)?

Comment: @jeremyharris If I make the Ajax request via `controller/filter.json` (with `Router::parseExtensions('json');` enabled  then there are no `X-Wf` headers but the Content-Type is set to `application/json`. If I disable `Router::parseExtensions('json');` and make the request to `controller/filter` then the `X-Wf` headers ARE generated but the Content-Type is `text/html`. I'm using PHP's `json_encode()` for the output in the view in both cases.

Comment: @jeremyharris BTW, the vendor import of `FirePHP.class.php` mentioned in your blog post doesn't seem to be necessary with the latest DebugKit as it seems to use it's own internal instance of FirePHP.

Comment: thanks, I'll update the post! I also fixed that redirect issue you mentioned. If there are no `X-Wf` headers in the response, that means that debug kit isn't even sending anything to firebug which sounds like a bug in DebugKit. It could be related to the one you posted (though it's not specifically that one).

Comment: @jeremyharris Ok, well, I've posted what I'm experiencing on the Lighthouse bug ticket so hopefully someone will be able to tell me if it's the same bug or not. If it isn't, I'll open a new one. Nobody else has contributed to this question so if you'd like to answer it to confirm that I'm doing everything right and that it sounds like a bug, I will happily mark it as the correct answer :-)

Comment: Your ticket says that you *are* using serialization when you're not. Might want to correct that so there's no confusion :) As for answering, you did all the work debugging the problem! I'd suggest you put an answer, add the ticket link, and accept it so future people know what's up.

Comment: @jeremyharris - ah, I thought using json_encode was tantamount to using serialization. I've updated the ticket to clarify now. I've also 'answered' my questions as per your suggestion. Thanks and Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this might be a documented bug:

http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42880/tickets/107-firephp-messages-are-not-sent-in-response-if-using-jsonxmlview-with-serialization

My usage case is not exactly the same, but outputting json is stopping the FirePHP headers from appearing. If I turn off the parse extensions directive for json, the FirePHP headers appear as they should.